# Vaadin 7 CustomComponent with @StyleSheet referencing image URL - Rejecting published file request for file that has not been published

Tags: java, css, vaadin

I got an **Rejecting published file request for file that has not been published** for a custom Vaadin 7 component with an image referenced in the css:

```
StyleSheet("mycomponent.css")
@JavaScript( { "mycomponent1.js", "mycomponent2.js"})
public class MyComponent extends AbstractJavaScriptComponent { 
    //...
}
```

In mycomponent.css I have

```
background-image: url(mycomponent-bg.png);
```

and Vaadin tells me:

> Rejecting published file request for file that has not been published: mycomponent-bg.png

Looking at the **PublishedFileHandler** in Vaadin 7 it says:

> Serves a connector resource from the classpath if the resource has previously been registered by calling LegacyCommunicationManager#registerDependency(String, Class). Sending arbitrary files from the classpath is prevented by only accepting resource names that have explicitly been registered. Resources can currently only be registered by including a {@link JavaScript} or {@link StyleSheet} annotation on a Connector class.

Doing a manual registration in the Component doesn't work:

```
 LegacyCommunicationManager lcm = new LegacyCommunicationManager(this.getSession());
 lcm.registerDependency("mycomponent-bg.png", this.getClass()); // 1.try
 lcm.registerDependency("mypath/mycomponent-bg.png", this.getClass()); // 2.try
```

Question: **What is the right way to have css styled custom components with images in Vaadin 7?** OR: **How can I add a arbitrary file to the dependencies?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to this problem would be, to add static image resources to a subfolder of /VAADIN/ as all resources contained within this folder can always be accessed directly and in a static manner or even move the stylesheet and all images used by it to a Vaadin theme (for details on how to do this, please refer to the [Themes chapter](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/themes.html) in the Book of Vaadin).

An alternative (although a rather messy one) would also be to make the required image files a dependency of your component by including them in the @JavaScript annotation, which will lead to them being correctly published along with your component and its stylesheets, but will also produce an error in your browser when viewing the page.

Regarding this topic, there is also a (now closed) [ticket](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/9934) and a [forum thread](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/2996912) which further details the solutions mentioned above.

Comment: Thank's. Using a full reference in the css file to the  "/VAADIN/mycomponent/mycomponent-bg.png" worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

for Vaadin 7 ... If your external javascript or css loads images then it should be placed in /VAADIN/ folder . for example if we have a file named common.js inside /VAADIN/js directory , you can refer the same in java UI or AbstractJavaScriptComponent  file using the path @JavaScript({"vaadin://js/common.js"}) and put all the image files relative to that directory ... it will work fine ....

Comment: This is the preferable solution if the project is setup via the Vaadin 7 Eclipse plugin, especially if you have different components using the same JS library (Vaadin will take care of it and load it only once). Otherwise, for those using Maven, the `src/main/resources/` can be used for the JS together with `src/main/java` (where the Java components are located).

Answer (score -1):

```
@StyleSheet(..your css..)
public class YourAddonClass ... {

  static {
    VaadinSession.getCurrent().getCommunicationManager().
                registerDependency("mycomponent-bg.png",
    ClassInSamePackageAsmycomponent-bg.class);
   }

}
```

Comment: Explanation may be helpful.